# kendo chart - change individual markers type,size and border color on the same series

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a kendo line chart which needs to have different marker styling for each data point.

I have the following template (markerType, size and border color are hardcoded and i am trying to make it dynamic )

```
<kendo-chart>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="categories">
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-series>
      <kendo-chart-series-item type="line" field="values" [data]="chartData">
        <kendo-chart-series-item-markers [type]="markerType" [size]="30" [border]="{color: 'green'}">
        </kendo-chart-series-item-markers>
      </kendo-chart-series-item>
    </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

And the following component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {  LineItem } from '../../../model/external-model';
import { MarkerType } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';

@Component({
  selector: 'line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.scss']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {
  categories: string[];
  values: number[];
  @Input() public chartData:LineItem[] = [];
  public markerType: MarkerType = "cross";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = this.chartData.map(x => x.category);
    this.values = this.chartData.map(x => x.values);
  }
}
```

And LineItem is as below.

```
export interface LineItem {
  category: string
  values: number
  marker: Marker
}

export interface Marker {
  size: number
  type: MarkerType
  background: string
}
```

My expected result is to have a line chart having each data point of varied size, shape(circle, cross, triable,square) and border color. So I would like to bind the size, type and background of 'Marker' to kendo-chart-series-item-markers -  type, size and border.

Could not find a way to use 'dataItem'(similar to the way kendo tool tip works) to get the individual data point values.  How do i implement this?

If using 'visual' of 'SeriesMarkers' the only only way to implement this, please help me with a sample code.

Comment: I have implemented this one using visual(Will post the code shortly). But i believe there must be a easier way to implement this.